# Set image in itemTpl dynamically in Sencha Touch List

Tags: list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, itemtemplate

I have to set an image with text in a row of my List.  But image is to be chosen at runtime.

Here is my Store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Sample', {
           extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

           config: {
           fields: [ 
                    { name: 'uName', mapping: '@name' },
                    { name: 'uId', mapping: '@id' }
                    ]
                }
           });
```

In my list itemTpl, I am able to display **uName**, and i have created a function(getImageURL) that is suppose to return the required image, so how shall i use or what is the way/syntax of using  **uId** from the above ( which has a value of either 0 or 1)

And here is my list:

```
  itemTpl : new Ext.XTemplate("<img src=\"{[this.getImageURL()]}\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\"></img><span>    {uName}</span>",
              {
               getImageURL : function()
                {

                // I have to return either of two images
                // if  uId = 0, return 'resources/images/Image0.png'
                // if uId = 1, return 'resources/images/Image1.png'

                }
              }
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a function. `XTemplate` provide `if` and `else` statements.

[Take a look at it here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)

**Example**

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<p>Name: {name}</p>',
    '<p>Kids: ',
    '<tpl for="kids">',
        '<p>{name} is a ',
        '<tpl if="age &gt;= 13">',
            '<p>teenager</p>',
        '<tpl elseif="age &gt;= 2">',
            '<p>kid</p>',
        '<tpl else>',
            '<p>baby</p>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</tpl></p>'
);
```

Hope this helps